# URISyntaxException while concatenating double quotes " " to a URL

Tags: java, url, exception, ioexception, interrupted-exception

I have

```
public List<Attraction> retrieveByQuery(String query, int page, int size) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String URL = "http://mydomain/get-by-query?";    
    URL += "query=" + query + "&page=" + page + "&size=" + size;

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest
                .newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .uri(URI.create(URL)) // thows URISyntaxException
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> httpResponses = httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());


        return null;
    }
```

- This is giving me

> URISyntaxException

how can I fix? I think the problem is with `""` (double quotes).

**EDIT**

This is the full stack strace with exceptions and details:

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 126: http://.../get-by-query?query=name=="Casa Lucio Dalla"&page=0&size=100
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:883)
    at dao_implementations.AttractionDAO_MongoDB.retrieveByQuery(AttractionDAO_MongoDB.java:119)
    at controllers.CrudAttractionController.doRetrieveByQuery(CrudAttractionController.java:505)
    at controllers.CrudAttractionController.lambda$buttonConfermaClicked$9(CrudAttractionController.java:451)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 126: http://Troppadvisorserver-env.eba-pfsmp3kx.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/attraction/search-by-rsql-no-point?query=name=='Casa Lucio Dalla';certificateOfExcellence==false&page=0&size=100
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2913)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3084)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3172)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3114)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:600)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:881)
    ... 49 more
```

followed by:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 126: http://.../get-by-query?query=name=="Casa Lucio Dalla"&page=0&size=100
```

Note that if I use a query with no spaces, for example `Casa` instead of `Casa Lucio Dalla` it works perfectly.

**EDIT2**

If I use `URL += "query=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + "&page=" + page + "&size=" + size;`, it gives me Error 500 internal server error

Comment: Could you post a full stack trace please?

Comment: The problem is *most likely* that the value of `query` contains characters not allowed in a URL, and you forgot to **URL encode** the value. Can't know for sure, since you haven't provide actual values. Try using `URL += "query=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(query) + "&page=" + page + "&size=" + size;` to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Already tried with UrlEncoder but still gives that essors

Comment: If server gives you `Error 500 internal server error`, then look at server logs to figure out why. Anyway, that's a different question. This question has been answered, and you should **accept** the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URL encode the `query` part of the URL.

If the URL should contain a `"` character, it must be in the form of `%22`.

Here's some code:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

...

URL += "query=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + "&page=" + page + "&size=" + size;
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

### **Update:**

> If I use *[the above suggestion]*, it gives me Error 500 internal server error

This means that the URL in created properly, and that the request reaches the server. Please post a new question with the server side error if you can't figure that out.

Comment: Hmm, I could reproduce your original issue, and then resolve it by doing the above change.

Comment: @user14229458 Can't be same error, because the string would be different. It string is the same, then you didn't do what this answer says.